# Why ExpansionTile page is deprecated?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I just want to know why ExpansionTile widget page is deprecated in flutter dev docs and What is the alternative?

https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample

**Is using ExpansionTile is unsafe?**

Answer (score 1):

ExpansionTile is not yet deprecated, but the sample page is deprecated as it contains some outdated stuff.  So you can use the documentation instead.

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) is the official documentation and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0b8abb4724/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart#L30) is the source code.

Answer (score 1):

ExpansionTile is not deprecated but the sample page showing is deprecated. check api at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html